# Math operations with null

Tags: c#

Please explain why this test passes?

```
[Test]
public void TestNullOps()
{
    Assert.That(10 / null, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(10 * null, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(10 + null, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(10 - null, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(10 % null, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(null / 10, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(null * 10, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(null + 10, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(null - 10, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(null % 10, Is.Null);

    int zero = 0;
    Assert.That(null / zero, Is.Null);
}
```

I don't understand how this code even compiles.

Looks like each math expression with null returns `Nullable<T>` (e.g. `10 / null` is a `Nullable<int>`). But I don't see operator methods in `Nullable<T>` class. If these operators are taken from `int`, why the last assertion doesn't fail?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types):

The predefined unary and binary operators and any user-defined operators that exist for value types may also be used by nullable types. These operators produce a null value if the operands are null; otherwise, the operator uses the contained value to calculate the result.

That's why all the test are passed, including the last one - no matter what the operand value is, if another operand is `null`, then the result is `null`.

Comment: Note that `==` has slightly different rules here; if *both* are null, it is `true`

Comment: Yep, and the same goes for `!=` as far as I know - if one is null, and another is not, then the result is `true`.

Comment: For another remark, the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) do not return nullable values; they simply return false if either or both operands are null.

Answer (score 21):

The operators for `Nullable<T>` are so-called "lifted" operators]; the c# compiler takes the operators available for `T` and applies a set of pre-defined rules; for example, with `+`, the lifted `+` is `null` if either operand is null, else the sum of the inner values. Re the last; again, division is defined as `null` if either operand is `null` - it never *performs* the division.

Comment: Could it be that the compiler just translate it into something else? See my answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell If division is never performed, why the compiler doesn't compile `Assert.That(null / 0, Is.Null);`?

Comment: @altso - I'm confused; you stated "why the last assertion doesn't fail" - and indeed, it ***doesn't*** fail (AFAIK) - `null/0` is `null`... ?

Comment: @MarcGravell There is a difference between assertion from post and my comment. In comment zero is a constant. And compiler fails on it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried seeing the generated code from the code below using reflector

```
var myValue = 10 / null;
```

And the compiler turns it into this:

```
int? myValue = null;
```

And this wont compile, so you cant trick it:

```
object myNull = null;
var myValue = 10 / myNull;
```

Comment: Yes, but that just restates the question, since **in both cases** it is the compiler doing this (using the same rules) - simply, it happens to be able to do it as a constant value in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the compiler converts `zero` to `Nullable<int>`, and provides the underlying division operator. Since the `Nullable` type may be null, the division by 0 is not caught during compile. Best guess is that they want you to be able to do null testing in cases where div/0 is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

The operations in this list always return NULL:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + NULL

5 * NULL - 7

'Home ' || 'sweet ' || NULL

MyField = NULL

MyField <> NULL

NULL = NULL
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time). Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: This doesn't look like C# to me. What language is this?

Comment: That was for general @sam

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer - it is about SQL, not C#. (And you should have kept the [link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-oper.html) as a part of the answer - it can be seen that the link is about Firebird SQL server.)