# C# - Convert String/Null to decimal

Tags: c#

I have a method and argument as a string or null. So I am trying to convert the arguments into decimal.. I am trying to use **decimal.Parse** to convert string to decimal.

If the argument has a null value don't want to convert as a decimal..

```cs
public void abcd(string price)
{
    decimal result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? null : decimal.Parse(price);
    //error - cannot convert null as decimal
    //I tried few other options also.
    decimal result = price is null ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);
    // error - VAlue cannot be null

    //have other logic here
}

abcd("123");
abcd(null);
```

Comment: `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: `decimal result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);` should work. And so should `decimal result = price is null ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);`

Comment: "_If the argument has a null value don't want to convert as a decimal_" - what do you want the value of result to be in that case?

Comment: Possible , If the argument has a null value don't want to convert as a decimal. because result mab be null or decimal value should have.

Comment: @RSKMR What should be the value of `result` if `price` is null?

Comment: @atiyar, Sorry maybe I am confusing.. my requirement is if the argument(price) has !=null then I should convert as decimal otherwise the result variable has null value..

Comment: The problem you are facing is that decimal is a value type, not nullable. That's why you are getting this compile time error. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: `decimal result = price is null ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);` seem to be doing exactly what question describes and does not produce any errors... What exactly is wrong with this variant? Or you are looking for some sort of "nullable value type in C#"? (like `decimal?`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a null to represent the absence of value, you can use a nullable variable:

```
decimal? result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? null : decimal.Parse(price);
```

This is a better option than representing a lack of data by a zero as proposed by others.

You may have to check if result is null before using it for certain purposes. However, the usual operations are supported:

See [Math operations with null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660449/math-operations-with-null)

Comment: "_representing a lack of data by a zero_" - is the default behavior in .NET for `decimal` type. And OP didn't mention they want a `null` for the `result`. That is why it is proposed by others.

Comment: @atiyar No. zero is a default value. It does not represent lack of data. There is a difference between saying I have zero euros on my account and I do not know (null). Moreover, you should never rely on a default value and explicitly assign a value instead.

Comment: @atiyar OP explicitly replied to you "... if the argument(price) has !=null then I should convert as decimal otherwise *the result variable has null value*". I'm not sure how you could interpret that as "OP didn't mention they want a `null` for the result". I agree that they should have edited that into the question (hence as it stands question is unclear).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I did read it. I'm talking about the other answers which were posted before OP made that clear.

Comment: @atiyar the other answers are just bad suggestions (for that exact reason - zero is not an invalid/bad value for a variable of decimal type... but rather very common and frequently used one), so I think it is safe to ignore them. Such suggestion could be ok with an explanation what could go wrong... but none of them have such explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string i = null;

decimal result;
decimal.TryParse(i, out result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); // 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `0` when the string is `null` or empty.

Please follow the below answer.

```cs
public void abcd(string price)
{
    decimal result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? 0: decimal.Parse(price);   
}
```

Comment: If the argument has a null value don't want to convert as a decimal..

Comment: Or if it isn't numeric

Answer (score -1):

Try -

```
public static void abcd(string price)
{
    decimal result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);
    decimal result2 = price is null ? 0 : decimal.Parse(price);

    //have other logic here
}
```